# extracting data from MariaDB using a raw KNEX statement

Tags: npm, mariadb, knex.js

Former sequelize person here.

What is the best method to extract data from MariaDB using a raw Knex statement?  Here are the two methods i have tried:

MariaDb:

```
   SELECT    JSON_OBJECT(
                 ...........
              )  'JSON_OBJECT'
```

jscript to interpret results:

```
for ( tmp of result[0] ) {   console.log (JSON.parse(tmp.JSON_OBJECT)) ; }
```

and this MariaDb:

```
     SELECT    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                  JSON_OBJECT(
                      ..........
                  )
                )  'JSON_ARRAYAGG'
```

jscript:

```
for ( tmp of JSON.parse(result[0][0]['JSON_ARRAYAGG'] )) { console.log(tmp)  ;  }
```

Both of these methods work, but there may be a much cleaner way rather than using `JSON.parse`.

Suggestions?

note:  i certainly understand there is a controversy using `raw` - i have a number of very large sql statements that were in a previous application, and i would rather (for now) just use them as is rather than rewrite them in pure Knex.

**EDIT**:   this may be "good enough" since it appears that knex raw does not necessarily return objects.

node:

```
     SELECT    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                  JSON_OBJECT(
                      ..........
                  )
                )  'JSON_ARRAYAGG'
  .....................................
const result = await knex.raw( sqlStatement, sqlQuery);
return result[0][0].JSON_ARRAYAGG   ;
```

browser:

```
(async () => { try { let result = await  app.service('raw-service').find({query: sqlQuery}) ; newResult = result; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }  } )() ;
console.log(JSON.parse(newResult));
```

but at least the really ugly stuff is hidden away, inside of node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL databases are designed to return rows of columns; any query where you route everything through json instead is not going to be "the best method" you ask for.

Your first try at least uses rows, so is better than the second.

That said, if you are just modifying existing code to work with Knex rather than rewriting it, whatever requires minimum changes will lead to fewer bugs and should be preferred.

Comment: your final comment is great.  i can easily live with the extremely minor workaround.  
yes sql db's return rows, and MariaDB has JSON_OBJECT to compensate for this.

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from a MariaDB database using Knex, you can use the .select() method on a Knex query builder object. This method allows you to specify the columns that you want to retrieve from the database, as well as any conditions or filters using the .where() method.

Comment: yes i agree with you for the smaller NEW queries, but i have many very large SQL statements that used to exist in a PHP script.   so for now, i need to use the statements "as is", hence the need to use just one big RAW statement.